# Cant call static list from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

I'm kinda new to programming... And having trouble finding any documentation regarding this eksampel
Ive managed to call this webservice from a console application, with no problem.

I'm now trying to call the same service from á webformes soulution. Ive placed the classes in the app_code folder.

I have defiend the JobOfferService class.. But when im trying to call the GetJobOffers() in the class, i not finding it ?

> JobOfferService js = new JobOfferService();

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  js. ?? - Error right here??

} 




public class JobOfferService
    {
        private const string Url = "https://www.xxx.com/api/v1/xxxxxx/";

    public static List<JobOffer> GetJobOffers()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var response = client.DownloadString(Url);
            var jobOffers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JobOffer>>(response);

            return jobOffers;
        }
    }
}

public class JobOffer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ContactInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a static method, you should be able to do

```
var jobOffers = JobOfferService.GetJobOffers();
```

Comment: Yeah i know right? .... I'm even trying do add some test metods in the JobOfferService class.. I'm now getting acces to my test metods, but not the GetJobOffers() metod... dont know what is wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

Make GetJobOffers() method a instance method. Just remove static keyword.

Or make JobOfferService class static too.